# Re-route connections to another external server

Tags: proxy, connection, redirect

I am trying to redirect a game that makes a HTTP request from one host to another host, so that I can intercept the value, and change the value as I need.

The game does not use TLS.

How can I achieve this redirect?

Comment: This sounds like a [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this? You should also describe a bit more details about what you try to do... Because it basically does not make sense as it is written.

Comment: @vidarlo i am trying to redirect a game value that makes an http request to get the value, and by forwarding the url i can set the value to anything i want

Comment: Can you make the game use a proxy? Does the game use TLS?

Comment: @vidarlo no, it does not use TLS.

Comment: Then it should be rather straight forward to redirect in by forcing it to use a proxy, either by editing `/etc/hosts`, or asking it to use a proxy. Please check with my rephrasing of your question to see if it accurately describes what you're trying to do. If not, just [edit] it to suit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo route add` and `sudo route del` commands allow you to edit the routing tables, which contain specifications which interface and which gateway are used for accessing a given target host or network. See `man route` for details.

`route` without any other parameters displays the current routing tables.